# What configuration is correct for Static IP?

Tags: server, ip-address

First, yes, this question's "question" will be an exact duplicate of [static ip - what am I doing wrong?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75249/static-ip-what-am-i-doing-wrong) , but the question was never resolved in a way that helps.

What I am trying to do is make my Ubuntu Server have a static IP address. I am not entirely sure on the numbers to plug in, but I am sure it has something to do with correctly setting up the DNS servers.

Information I have:

- I want the address of the computer to be `192.168.1.99`.
- The router's address is `192.168.1.1`.
- The subnet mask is `255.255.255.0`.
- I **assume** that the network is `192.168.1.0`.
- I **assume** that the broadcast is `192.168.1.255`.
- According to my router, the DNS servers are `75.75.75.75` and `75.75.75.76`. No idea if this is correct or not.

This is what my files look like currently:

**/etc/network/interfaces**

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.99
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway 192.168.1.1
```

**/etc/resolv.conf**

```
#these are all commented out, I was trying ideas, but no combinations worked.
#nameserver 75.75.75.75
#nameserver 75.75.76.76
#nameserver 8.8.8.8
#search hsd1.nh.comcast.net
```

Currently, as with the similar question, I can ping every other computer on my local network. But as soon as I try to `ping www.google.com`, I get `unknown host www.google.com`.

If anyone has any suggestions, it would help a lot.

suggestion: [Why doesn't this custom static IP network configuration work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170420/why-doesnt-this-custom-static-ip-network-configuration-work) (the first comment)

Comment: gateway 192.1.8.1.1  <-- type-o there , should be 192.168.1.1

Comment: sorry, that is correct. typo on my part

Comment: Did you try the router `nameserver 192.168.1.1` in your `/etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: still nothing, sorry

Comment: is your server running from a static ip to start with? If it is dynamic there is a few extra things needed I think.

Comment: I would like it to be a static IP all the time. I do not want the IP address to change ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I am not sure why, but I got it to work. I am not going to mark it as the answer until I am conviced that I solved the issue.

First what I did was go to [this tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-configure-a-static-ip-address-tutorial/), and noticed that they have `search cyberciti.biz` in their `/etc/resolv.conf` file, followed by the dns servers they want to use. Remembering that this "search" line is similar to the one that was automatically generated in my copy of the file, I formatted the file to look like this:

```
search hsd1.nh.comcast.net
nameserver 68.87.71.226
nameserver 68.87.73.242
```

These DNS number I had to get from [this website](http://www.whatsmydns.net/dns/usa/comcast.html) (I use comcast).

I restarted the computer and magicly I can ping Google! Also, the `search` line has been removed from the `/etc/resolv.conf` file, but I think that's ok.

Also, I don't know if this helps/hurts, but I put in the line

```
dns-nameservers 68.87.71.226 68.87.73.242
```

in my `/etc/network/interfaces` file, as the last line.

I will update this post if this turns out to work or not.

Comment: did you mean 'nameserver 68.87.71.226' instead of 'namespace' ?

Comment: The 'dns-nameservers' line is in fact necessary because Ubuntu uses 'resolvconf' and 'dnsmasq' to give you a local cache, so those are used to populate the configs for those programs, and then they take over /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: yes, I meant "nameserver". I've been doing too much programming lately. Typo here, not in my file.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a local DNS server in your LAN?

If not, try to put Google DNS or Open DNS in your `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Google DNS is: `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`
Open DNS is: `208.67.222.222` and `208.67.220.220`

The syntax is:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Also maybe you need to restart networking after that, but I am not sure:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

On Windows you would flush the DNS cache, but Ubuntu doesn't cache DNS by default I think.

Comment: I do not have a local DNS server in my lan. I have tried both Google's DNS and OpenDNS in that file. Still no dice. And I have been restarting the network service with `service networking restart`.

Comment: Here is an interesting tid-bit: when I restart using that command, I get on the first line: `stop: Unknown instance:`. But then I can still ping all the computers on my local network.

Comment: Hm I am not sure what that means... Do you have Samba installed on your machine? There have been cases where `dns proxy = yes` in `/etc/samba/smb.conf` interfered with the main DNS settings.

Comment: I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, if that is what you mean. There is no such "samba" directory in `/etc/`.

Comment: I guess then it's not installed. Samba is the name of a server software providing Windows File Sharing and Printing Services.

Comment: Why would it matter that I install Samba? My Linux box is not communicating directly with any computers except for the router and the internet.